# What are the union and intersection of events?

Tags: probability

I know what the union and intersection of sets are, but I don't understand how that applies to probability and events.(As in, why is the probability of the intersection of 2 events the probability of both events happening, and what sets are intersecting) A good explanation of events would also be helpful.

Comment: Short answer: Events are sets of outcomes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In probability we restrict our attention to a special set called the **sample space.** This contains all possible outcomes of an experiment. Now **events** are just subsets of this sample space. Given two events $A$ and $B$, their intersection and union are also events. They are defined in the same way they are for sets; namely
$$
A\cap B := \{x\in S \mid x\in A\ \text{and}\ x\in B\}
$$
and
$$
A\cup B := \{x\in S \mid x\in A\ \text{or}\ x\in B\},
$$
where $S$ denotes the sample space.
Thus if we want to find the probability that both $A$ and $B$ happen, we compute the probability of the intersection. Likewise for union.

Comment: But what if the events are in separate sample spaces(like the probability of getting a 6 on a roll of a die and getting a 2 on a 4 spaced spinner. Is that still an intersection?)

Comment: @Heatblast016 The sample space has all possible outcomes. So if the experiment consists of rolling a die and spinning a spinner with $4$ spaces, then our sample space may look something like
$$
\{(x,y) \mid x\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\},\,y\in\{1,2,3,4\} \}
$$
Then the event that we get a $6$ on the roll would be
$$
A:=\{(6,1),(6,2),(6,3),(6,4)\}
$$
and the event of getting a $2$ on the spinner would be
$$
B:=\{(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2),(6,2)\}.
$$
Then $A\cap B=\{(6,2)\}$. Assuming the die and the spinner are both fair, we get
$$
P(A\cap B) = \frac{|A\cap B|}{|S|} = \frac{1}{24}.
$$

Comment: Assuming the outcomes are unbiased.

Answer (score 0):

We model an event as a set of outcomes.

For example, let $\Omega = \{$ Raining, Sunny, Windy $\}$

Then we might want to ask "what's the probability of tomorrow being either Raining or Windy"?

Here, "being raining or windy" is an event that we could measure with a probability. And actually it is easy to see that this event could be represented by the set $A = \{$ Raining, Windy $\}$, which is a subset of $\Omega$. And you could also express $A$ as intersection or union of other events, for example, $A = \{$ Raining $\} \cup\{$ Windy $\}$.

Answer (score 0):

A *sample space* is the set of all possible outcomes.

An event is a subset of this *sample space*.   That is, an event is a set of outcomes.

Which is why we talk about their intersections, unions, and complements; may describe them as disjoint; and such.

The *probability measure* for an event is the expectation that the realised outcome is(or will be) a member of the event.

(The *realised outcome* is the one outcome that happened, occured, resulted, or other synonym.)

---

(Later you will learn that the *sample space* is coupled with a *sigma-algebra* and a *probability measure* to form a *probability space*.   The *sigma-algebra* of that *probability space* is basically the set of all measurable events.)